# Could not find SDK "WindowsMobile, Version=10.0.18362.0" error in VS17 when deploying to HoloLens

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine, hololens

I'm new to HoloLens (and Microsoft's ecosystem) and am following [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/holograms-101) to learn. One of the steps is to deploy from Visual Studios to HoloLens, but when I try to I get this run-time error.
[image: VS17 run-time error]
I have confirmed that I have followed [this guide from Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/install-the-tools) to set up my development environment, but my error still persists.

In Unity, these are by build settings and Player settings as instructed in the tutorial:
[image: Build Settings]
[image: Other Settings]
[image: XR Settings]

My Windows 10 computer is running on 1903, my HoloLens is on 1804, and I have both Windows SDK 10.0.17x and 10.0.18x installed on my computer (via Visual Studios installer and [this link](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk)). I have also tested deploying the app using the 10.0.17x SDK, but end with the same results.

I can simulate my app from Unity using the Holographic Remoting app in HoloLens, but I just can't deploy it from Visual Studios. What is causing this error and how can I solve it?

**Update:**

I have tried re-installing the Windows 10 SDK (both 10.0.17x and 10.0.18x), but this did not resolve the problem. My Windows 10 SDK is installed in my D: drive if that would make any difference.

**Update 2:**

I read somewhere that if you simply delete those files from the project tree in Visual Studios, the error will go away. Indeed it did and I could build and run just fine after that seemly without issue, but there must be something wrong with deleting SDK files like that... Is deleting them safe?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

I managed to get this to work by deleting the reference to the Mobile SDK in the vxcproj file. It doesn't seem to be required!
App deployed to Hololens successfully!

Comment: This is stilla  problem today; Unload project, edit project file, delete the line <SDKReference Include="WindowsMobile, Version=10.0.22621.0" />

Answer (score 0):

According to the error message from the picture you post, there seems to be a problem with your Windows 10 sdk. Please check if the files in this directory are damaged (C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Extension SDKs\WindowsMobile\10.0.18362.0), and try to reinstall the Windows10 SDK:https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk

Comment: So I re-installed the SDK (both 10.0.17x and 10.0.18x) and the problem persists. Would it matter though if I had it installed in my D: drive?

Comment: Sorry for the delayed reply. I noticed your update, would you like to share your workaround and reference link of it?

Answer (score 0):

this issue happens when you install your Visual Studio to somewhere else other than DISC C. I found a good explanation about this issue and how to work through

[Could not find SDK WindowsMobile](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/msb3774-could-not-find-sdk-windowsmobile-version10/402362#:%7E:text=It%20happens%20when%20Visual%20Studio,%5C10%5CExtension%20SDKs%5C.)