# VS 2019 could not find SDK

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine, hololens, mrtk

I keep getting this error, I am trying to perform the unity MRTK tutorial for hololens 2. I did everything on the first page https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/mr-learning-base-02. When I try and run it this error comes up. I have tried to install 10.0.19041.0 through windows but it always kicks to 19041.1 I have installed all the required components in visual studio.

Any help would be appreciated.

[Error pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rf6Cu.png)

[Installed Vs individual components](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8NUxm.png)

[Unity Build settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uEt5S.png)

Answer (score 2):

The problem you met is a bug seemingly caused by vs installer. It happens when Visual Studio is not installed on driver C.

You can see it here:
https://developercommunity2.visualstudio.com/t/HoloLens-2-build-fails-if-Windows-sdk-is/1313568

There are many ways you could do to get through this.

1. Copy the folder `[Windows Kit Root Dir]\10\Extension SDKs\WindowsMobile` (For e.g., `D:\Windows Kits\10\Extension SDKs\WindowsMobile`) to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Extension SDKs\`. Should solve all of the missing WindowMobile issues.
   https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/msb3774-could-not-find-sdk-windowsmobile-version10/402362#T-N474809
2. Delete the reference to the Mobile SDK in the vxcproj file.
   https://stackoverflow.com/a/60600054/9522354

I tried the first method and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

> I have tried to install 10.0.19041.0 through windows but it always kicks to 19041.1

For how to modify the `SDKReference` version, you can try following step:

By referring Section 5 of [Update your C#/VB projects to use the latest Universal Windows Platform](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/misc/migrate-apps-to-the-universal-windows-platform-uwp?view=vs-2015&redirectedfrom=MSDN&viewFallbackFrom=vs-2019#update-your-cvb-projects-to-use-the-latest-universal-windows-platform)

Right-click your existing project(YourProjectName(Universal Windows)) in solution explorer, then select Unload Project. After the project is unloaded, right-click the project file again and choose to edit the .vcxproj file.

Find "SDKReference" element and change the value of version from "10.0.19041.1" to your version like "10.0.19041.0".

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <SDKReference Include="WindowsMobile, Version=10.0.19041.1" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

to

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <SDKReference Include="WindowsMobile, Version=10.0.19041.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Besides, since you are using HoloLens2, it is recommended to set the Architecture in the Unity Build Setting window to x64.

Comment: I tried this but it did not work it still came up with the same error.. I also deleted the line from the unloaded code. It uploads and starts the unity program, but I don't know if this SDK is important for vuforia and unity on the hololens 2. Thanks though for showing me how to unload the file. Would have been lost without that

Comment: Just want to confirm with you, after you deleted this line, did the project deploy and work nice?  I find other threads in the forum say that their projects working properly after deleting the line. In addition, I also found this comment in the unity community, which may be helpful to you: [Error MSB3774 Could not find SDK "WindowsMobile, Version=10.0.16299.0"](https://forum.unity.com/threads/error-msb3774-could-not-find-sdk-windowsmobile-version-10-0-16299-0.525224/#post-4861337)

Comment: Yeh it worked kinda but i have another issue. I am using Vuforia with unity. I used the windows application; model target generator, to create both trained and untrained model targets. i deployed the targets in unity. first i tried in hololens 2 to test to see if the model targets would have the overlay. I got nothing. I bought a webcam to test the thing in unity and still it did not recognized the model. I am using a small object probably in the measurement range of .0# M I have done everything the tutorials have told me to do. Do you have any ideas. I am lost and in need of help asap

Comment: for comntext I am using model target generator 9.4.6 and I am using unity 2019.4.11f1 and i am using vuforia version 9.4.6

Comment: It is recommended that you repost a new question with Vuforia and Unity3d tags or ask for help in the Vuforia forum so that more Vuforia specialists will pay attention to it and provide professional advice.